# Not able to run ruby on rails on ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, amazon-web-services

I have installed ruby on rails using the below tutorial `https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.10` .I completed all the steps mentioned as per the tutorial and I could even create a rails app and run it using `rails server` .

When I used `rails server` , it showed me

```
ubuntu@ip-192-30-0-97:~/myapp$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.0 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2015-02-01 09:45:51] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-02-01 09:45:51] INFO  ruby 2.1.5 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux]
[2015-02-01 09:45:51] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=11899 port=3000
```

But when I navigate to my IP (Elastic IP pointing to my instance running Ubuntu 14.04),Im just getting a page "Website not available" .I could get this working on my local computer,when I navigated to the localhost IP the rails default page opened up,however here Im not able to get this working.

I am new to RoR and ubuntu,please help on this.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of rails 4.2, `rails s` by default only binds to the localhost interface. To bind to other interfaces use the `- b` option, for example

```
rails s -b 0.0.0.0
```

restores the behaviour of earlier rails versions. You'll still need to configure security group rules and any firewall running on the instance to allow incoming connections.

Usually one wouldn't use webrick for a production deployment though

Comment: Thanks , this worked like a charm! Now I can't keep the session always on SSH while I work.Is it possible for me to now install APACHE and Passenger after all this?

Comment: Yes, Apache/passenger is one of the ways to do this

Answer (score 0):

The webrick server seems to be running properly. You need to go to:

```
http://ipaddress:3000
```

And you should see the rails default page.

You can also try running webrick on port 80 like this:

```
rails s -p 80
```

And then simply accessing it with `http://ipaddress`

This is considering port 3000 or 80 are open on your server. If you are using Amazon EC2, check out their documentation:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html

Comment: This is not done on my local PC.I have created an amazon instance with ubuntu installation and pointed an elastic IP to my instance.When I type my IP address in the browser it just shows me,"This webpage is not available".

Comment: What do you enter in your address bar exactly?

Comment: The Public IP of my server where I have install the ruby on rails App.Note : I havn't installed apache / passenger in my server.I have created an ubuntu instance,but not apache/passenger.But since web rick is running,I should be able to see my application right?I have created my rails application at ' /home/ubuntu/myapp ' in my ubuntu server

Comment: @SarithaNair if you are in your development mode then you might need to put ip:port rather than just ip like 192.168.1.12:3000 where 192.168.1.12 is ip

Comment: Indeed, if port 3000 is open it should work. Check out my answer, don't forget to add :3000 at the end of the IP address.

Comment: @HaiderAli I have tried that as well,but its still the same

Comment: @SarithaNair  from you question it look like you are running server in development mode so please first try localhost:3000 in your browser

Comment: @MarcLainez Now how to open porT 3000?

Comment: @Haider he seems to be running in development mode on an amazon instance

Comment: @MarcLainez Yeah Im running on development mode.Is it not possible to run using my IP or point it?

Comment: @SarithaNair if you on amazon instance and running server in development mode then you should not close your ssh terminal window .... did you get my point ..?

Comment: @HaiderAli I have done the same.Paralelly by running SSH and the rails s command, I tried opening my IP as as IP:3000 . But no use.

Comment: @Saritha try running the server on port 80, check out my edited answer

Comment: @MarcLainez Still the same

Comment: My servers public IP is 54.174.0.9

Comment: The IP which you are seeing in my question is dummy.

Comment: Ok make sure port 3000 or 80 is open, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html

Comment: @MarcLainez I have attached a security group in which Im allowing port 80 ,22, and 443

Comment: @SarithaNair open another SSH session to your server and run command curl localhost:3000 and tell have your response in answer ..... because amazon might not be allowing inbound traffic but your rails server will definatley reply to request from inside of your network

Comment: @SarithaNair first try whatever **  Marc Lainez** is saying if not get success then i will guide you

Comment: @HaiderAli Awesome ! :) that worked from the SSH.Now how to point my IP addres so that I can see the same from the browser

Comment: get output of your rails server with this command `tail -f log/development.log` then hit ip_of_your_server:3000 from your browser and check if you get something inside your log .... if there is an error it will tell you else need to check other stuff ....

Comment: @SarithaNair going outside for few moment will reply you latter

Answer (score 0):

Here is the easiest way to install rvm, rails and ruby in one command only.
Run

> \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails

in terminal.
It's going to reject you first time, you have to import the key, just c/p the line above, it actually says you to do that. Then run the curl command again and voila, you have working rails environment.
Hope this helps.